# MATLAB graph wont show when i enter plot after ending function

Tags: matlab, plot, chaos

I get this:

> "This statement is not inside any function.
>    (It follows the END that terminates the definition of the function "plot_2_components".)"

I've tried entering plot before "end" but no plots showed up. Assuming the the variables have values assigned to them.

```
function [U,A] = beer_game_orbit(a,b,t,Q,x0,n, k)
    %create orbit in 15 x K matrix using a total of N matrix 

    A = zeros(15,n); 

    A(:,1) = x0; 
    for i =2:n
       %compute but do not store yet, iterate over first column
       A(:,i) = beer_game_function(a,b,t,Q,A(:,i-1)); 


    end

    U = A(:,n-k+1:n);

end

function [] = plot_2_components(k1,k2,U)
    %k1 and k2 are the components who we can to graph against each other 
    %U is the output of beer_game_orbit 

    m = size(U(k1,:),2); 

    figure(1); 
    clf; 

    for i = 1:m

        plot(U(k1,i),U(k2,i),'k*'); 
        hold on 

    end


    if(k1 == 1)
        str1 = 'FI'; 
    elseif k1 == 2
        str1 = 'FB'; 
    elseif k1 == 3
        str1 = 'FPD2'; 
    elseif k1 == 4
        str1 = 'FPD1'; 

    end

    if(k2 == 1)
        str2 = 'FI'; 
    elseif k2 == 2
        str2 = 'FB'; 
    elseif k2 == 3
        str2 = 'FPD2'; 
    elseif k2 == 4
        str2 = 'FPD1'; 
    elseif k2 == 5

    end

    title(['Plot of ' str1 ' vs ' str2]);
end

Run [U] = beer_game_orbit(a,b,t,Q,x0,n,k)
plot_2_components(1,4,U)
```

Thank you!

Comment: I tried fixing up your code formatting but I don't understand the end that starts with "`Run [U]`", please [edit] your question and make sure it makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to create a [script file that contains local functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions-in-scripts.html) (**NOTE:** only supported in R2016b or later). If that's true, then you have to move your local functions *after* the code you want to run in your script. Your file should look something like this:

```
[U] = beer_game_orbit(a,b,t,Q,x0,n,k);  % Code to run
plot_2_components(1,4,U);               % Code to run

function [U,A] = beer_game_orbit(a,b,t,Q,x0,n, k)  % Local function

  % Code for beer_game_orbit...

end

function [] = plot_2_components(k1,k2,U)  % Local function

  % Code for plot_2_components...

end
```

If your file *starts* with a function, then it will be treated like a [function file](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-functions-in-files.html) and not a script. The first function is the main function (which is what is called from outside the file) while any subsequent functions are [local functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html) (which can only be called from within the file). Function files can't define any code outside of a [function definition](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html), hence the error you're getting.